# How can I find length of iterator in python without exhausting it?

Tags: python, iterator

I have the following use case:

1. Call a function which returns iterator in python
2. Check if iterator is not empty
3. If not empty, then do some operation

However, the process of checking if the iterator is empty, seems to empty it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, since most iterators don't know the length themselves, and an iterator can be *infinite*: for instance `itertools.repeat`.

Comment: You don't need the length of an iterable to check if it is empty.  You just need to try to take one item out of it.  Depending on the use case, you can just use that item directly before processing the rest of the iterable, or you can use the item and the iterable to construct a _new_ iterable which you can then process.

Comment: Usually you iterate over an iterator and when it is empty there will be no iteration.

Comment: You're describing Schrödinger's iterator.  "the process of checking if the iterator is empty, seems to empty it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a copy of an iterator so that you can operate on it independently of the original, you can use [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).  You can test if an iterator is empty by seeing if it throws StopIteration.

So you could do something like:

```
def isempty(it):
    try:
        itcpy = itertools.tee(it,1)[0]
        itcpy.next()
        return False
    except StopIteration:
        return True

def empty_iterator():
    if False:
        yield

it = empty_iterator()
if not isempty(it):
    # won't print
    print(len(list(it)))

it = xrange(4)
if not isempty(it):
    # will print
    print(len(list(it)))
```

Comment: This will not work. `xrange` is not an iterator, it is an *iterable*. Try this with `x = xrange(4); it = iter(x)`. You will see that if you do `isempty(it)`, then try `len(list(it))` you will get 3. Note, since `xrange` is a sequence type, to check if it is empty, you can simply do `if x:`. Or try `bool(xrange(0))` and `bool(xrange(1))`

Comment: BTW if you don't believe me that `xrange` objects are not iterators, try `next(xrange(10))` and see what the python interpreter has to say about it.